# PCFDEV: Pivotal Network returned: 451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

This is an informational post about a recent problem I encountered when installing PCFDEV for use in development and testing.

On Ubuntu-16.04 server core, when I was starting PCFDEV as follows ...

```
cf dev start
```

... I was getting the error "Pivotal Network returned: 451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons".

I was using this within the proper terms and conditions (local development and/or integration testing) and my email and password are correct. Why was I getting this error?

Possible Reasons and/or Solutions:

1. Make Sure to Download the most recent version of PCFDEV (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44029486/1669464).
2. Logging into the Pivotal.io website with the credentials being used may resolve the issue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44094847/1669464).

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem just recently. I logged in at [pivotal's network](https://network.pivotal.io) and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was caused by an outdated version of PCFDEV I had downloaded a month ago.

Downloading a fresh copy and running the plugin installer will upgrade the plugin to the most recent version. The error went away after this.